# Convert multiline result to a single line for a txt file in file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I check in a dataframe if there are duplicates in a column. If so I would like to have the result written to a file.

The Code

```
if len(duplicate_tgt_ch_name_df.tgt_ch_name.str.lower()) != 0:
    file_log.write(f"{init_time} Init - " + str(duplicate_tgt_ch_name_df.tgt_ch_name))
```

give me this:

```
2020-04-27 22:30:56 Init - 2    Wetter_Lt
3    Wetter_Lt
Name: tgt_ch_name, dtype: object
```

How can i convert this to:

```
2020-04-27 22:30:56 Init - 2    Wetter_Lt 3    Wetter_Lt?
```

Comment: I just removed some code that's not relevant to the question, but just wanted to mention as well, `else: pass` is pointless and you never need to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str(pandas.Series)` includes the dtype, and separates with newlines. Instead you could use `.to_string()` and replace the newlines with strings:

```
f"{init_time} Init - " + duplicate_tgt_ch_name_df.tgt_ch_name.to_string().replace('\n', ' ')
```

Comment: p.s. I don't use Pandas very often so lmk if there's a better way